# Having trouble showing canvas on screen JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, transparent

So, I'm quite new to JavaFX, and am trying to make an application with a transparent background and two red circles. The circles appear (in the little preview window) when I hover over the app icon in my taskbar, but don't show up on the screen.

EDIT: Using the Screen class rather than the awt stuff fixed it.

My code is:

```
package com.razorrider7.touchgame;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import com.razorrider7.touchgame.manager.SettingsManager;

public class TouchGame extends Application {

public static String dataFolder = System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + "TouchGame";

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
SettingsManager.setup();
initUI(stage);
}

private void initUI(Stage stage) {

stage.setResizable(false);

// Make the window transparent
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

Pane pane = new Pane();

double width = getBounds().getWidth(), height = getBounds().getHeight();

stage.setWidth(width);
stage.setHeight(height);
stage.setX(0);
stage.setY(0);


// Create new canvases for the left and right joysticks
Canvas joy1 = new Canvas(), joy2 = new Canvas();

joy1.setWidth(Math.rint(width / 6));
joy1.setHeight(Math.rint(width / 6));
joy2.setWidth(Math.rint(width / 6));
joy2.setHeight(Math.rint(width / 6));

joy1.setTranslateX(0);
joy1.setTranslateY(height - width / 6);
joy2.setTranslateX(width - width / 6);
joy2.setTranslateY(height - width / 6);

// Draw the joysticks
drawJoy(joy1);
drawJoy(joy2);

pane.getChildren().add(joy1);
pane.getChildren().add(joy2);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("TouchGame");
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stage.show();
}

private void drawJoy(Canvas canvas) {
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
gc.setFill(Color.RED);
gc.fillOval(1, 1, canvas.getWidth() - 1, canvas.getHeight() - 1);
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
Rectangle bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());

Rectangle safebounds = new Rectangle(bounds);
safebounds.x += insets.left;
safebounds.y += insets.top;
safebounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
safebounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
return safebounds;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, circles display no problem (OS X, Java 8u72).  I recommend you don't mix UI toolkits and remove all `java.awt` imports from your program.  Also, programming the scene graph rather than a canvas is usually easier.

Comment: Perhaps the equivalent that you can try for replacing your awt code is the JavaFX [Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class.

Comment: Yep that was it. Using the Screen class fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your awt code with the JavaFX [Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class.